# How to run ports 27000 to 27050 through nrgok?

Tags: ngrok

i want  to run the ports ranging from 27000 to 27050? Does ngrok have a way to do this? Im asking cause my current router has no support for portforwarding

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about forwarding port using ngrok then yes you can do it.

Install ngrok from https://ngrok.com/download and use the command `ngrok http <port>`

If you are looking to use range of ports then you need to specify them in ngrok config file. Something similar can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522360/ngrok-configure-multiple-port-in-same-domain).

Comment: uh, the thing you linked doesn't seem to contain anything as far as range ports, it shows multiple ports but not a range, and i wanted to do it for tcp mainly, im trying to use it to host a gaming session.