# ngrok not able to forward incoming webhook POST request to my local Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ngrok, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have a question for all you "ngtok" experts out there. I have a local Web API that exposes an endpoint that expects a webhook call. The webhook call is a POST message with a content-type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". My Web API method is declared like this:

```
   [Route("api/webhook")]
   [ApiController]
   public class WebhooksController : ControllerBase
   {
      // POST api/values
      [HttpPost]
      [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
      public void Post([FromForm] Response webHookResponse)
      {
         // these are here only to allow me to create a breakpoint
         int i = 0;
         i = 6;
      }
   }

   public class Response
   {
      [FromForm(Name = "code_id")]
      public string codeId { get; set; }

      [FromForm(Name = "name")]
      public string name { get; set; }

      [FromForm(Name = "address")]
      public string address { get; set; }
   }
```

I am running the Web API locally, so the API is listening to a port assigned by Visual Studio. If I call my endpoint from Postman, I get a nice HTTP Status response of 200 OK and I hit my breakpoint in my code.

In order to have the external application call my endpoint, I had ngrok installed and I am running  it locally with the command

```
   ngrok http http://localhost:44398
```

In my VS, I have unchecked the "Enable SSL" option so that the Web API is only started on HTTP, on port 44398.

I have configured the Webhook URL in the external system as this:

```
    https://4f2b-174-91-63-191.ngrok.io/api/webhook
```

The exact domain name varies as I restart ngrok, but I always use the one that is active.

When the external entity is sending the webhook POST message, I capture it in the ngrok console:

[image]

But my breakpoint is not reached. At the bottom of the ngrok console I see the following:

[image]

Any suggestion as to why is this happening? Am I not running ngrok with the proper command? Is there another way of doing it?

TIA,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions to install the ngrok extension for Visual Studio found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions

I also installed the ngrok NuGet package and I have added ngrok to my services as per this resource: https://github.com/kg73/NgrokAspNetCore

With these two things in place, starting the ngrok tunnel from Visual Studio, my breakpoint in the new Web API endpoint I created was reached.

I am not sure of the exact command that Visual Studio is using to start the ngrok tunnel. If anyone can shed some light, I'd be very interested in that, just to see what is the difference between the way I was starting it and the way VS is starting it.