# how to fix more than 3 tunnels are running over a single NGROK agent session

Tags: ngrok, beef

$

> grok start --all

Your account may not run more than 3 tunnels over a single ngrok agent session.
The tunnels already running on this session are:
tn_2HpYCEfpJb2VAiIPS, tn_2HpYCKQh6q9j9R3nyKiJ, tn_2HpYCIPYGWWN9f3am75

ERR_NGROK_324

I tried to stop the running process but I could not.
I searched everywhere but had no luck.
thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 10):

Ngrok automatically opens a http and https tunnel for every configuration.
Add bind_tls:true to your configs to only open one https and no http tunnel.
This way you can open three connections.

Example configuration:

```
tunnels:  
  first_service:  
    addr: 4200  
    proto: http  
    bind_tls: true
  second_service:
    addr: 8080
    proto: http
    bind_tls: true
  third_service:
    addr: 8085
    proto: http
    bind_tls: true
```